# Internal Server Error 500 laravel ubuntu14.04

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4, ubuntu-14.04, http-status-code-500

Options -MultiViews

```
RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

[image]

[image]

what is wrong?

Comment: if you got 500 error,then please check your server log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you've pointed your web server (Apache) to a `public` directory, not Laravel root directory.

Also set write permissions on a `storage` folder:

```
chmod -R 775 storage
```

Comment: chmod -R 775 storage     

did not help

Comment: Also point your web server to a `public` directory. Then restart web server.